# TcpClient doesn't connect, program freezes, server does not receive anything

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

```
    static void tcp()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Beginning...");
        System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 20061);
        TcpClient connection = new TcpClient();
        connection.Connect(ipEndPoint);
        NetworkStream stream = connection.GetStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteLine("/api/subscribe?source=console&key=d41c411558628535bbad927b1ad667c823e37a7e06e1b0a61ce707ed287bb4bb&show_previous=true");
        writer.Flush();
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line != "success")
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to connect");
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(line);
            Program.Form3 Form3 = new Program.Form3();
            Form3.textBox1.Text = Form3.textBox1.Text + "\r\n" + line;
        }
    }
```

This the code I got. I want to connect to my server waiting for requests over TCP. However, this code does not work, and I can't figure out why. When it was on main thread, the program was just freezing. Now, when it's on another thread (tcp()) nothing actually happens, and the server does not even receive anything.

**I checked if the server is fully working and operational, it 100% works.** I checked using SimpleTCP. (I connected to 127.0.0.1 over port 20061, and sent a command "/api/subscribe?source=console&key=d41c411558628535bbad927b1ad667c823e37a7e06e1b0a61ce707ed287bb4bb&show_previous=true", and started receiving strings I wanted.)

I just want to connect to TCP, send one command, and start receiving strings.

Oh, and I sure do call the thread, when I hit button "connect" the message box shows up.

Comment: Could you please add the code of the server implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `writer.Flush()` when you are finished writing the command. A `StreamWriter` is allowed to buffer data and write it when the buffer is full. `Flush()` flushes the write buffer, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added writer.Flush() after sending the command, but it still doesn't work. I added the flush to the question.